# How to pass Json Content in request Body Using http client with DeleteAsync Method (C#)?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Need to pass Json Content in Request body using http client DeleAsync Method in C#.Not able to pass the Request body in DeleteAsync Method.

```
HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
            var Ids = new[] { 100,202,304,866 };
            string endpoint=" URL goes here";
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ids);
            var RequestBody = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8);


             var response = client.DeleteAsync(endpoint,RequestBody).Result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this. As far as I know you can't have body in `DeleteAsync`

```
object jsonObj;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Delete,
        RequestUri = new Uri("yourUrl"),
        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```